# Amazon S3 daily data processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

There is a data being stored on a s3 bucket in a daily basis, we are trying to automate parsing and processing that daily data being sent to s3 bucket, we already have the script that will parse the data, we just need to have the approach on the AWS how to automate this,the approach/use-case we thought was AWS batch that is scheduled to do the script on a daily basis or will get the latest data on that day before EOD, but seems like batch is incapable of doing it.

any ideas and approach? we've seen some approach like using Lambda and SQS/SNS
just to summarize:

data (Daily) > stored in S3 > data will be process by our team > stored to elastic search.

Thanks your ideas.

Comment: Seems reasonable, assuming that you prefer to batch the processing. Every time an object is dropped into S3, a message is appended to an SQS queue. On some schedule, Batch pulls messages from SQS and processes the corresponding S3 object. Example: https://github.com/danilop/SampleBatchProcessing

Comment: Why specifically can't Batch do this? If the new file can be processed in under 5 minutes you could use Lambda for the processing, otherwise you could use Lambda to trigger some other sort of processing job in Batch or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Lambda + cloud watch events to execute your code on a regular schedule. You can specify a fixed rate ( or you can specify a Cron expression ), for example, in your case, you can execute your lambda every 24 hours, this way, your logic for data processing will run once daily.

Take a look at this article from AWS : [Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda is exactly what you want in this case.  You can trigger lambda executing on S3 file showing up, that will process the file, and can then send it to ElasticSearch or wherever you want it to end up.

Here's an official explanation from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html